# FullCalendar in hidden div

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, fullcalendar

I Have a fullCalendar, with dynamic data that is loaded with a external json file  to be rendered in a hidden div(a div inside a modal). After document ready, i'll load FC using:

```
$("#calendar").fullCalendar({
    lazyFetching: false,
    defaultDate: '$hoje',
    events: 'events.json'
});
```

When i open the modal, i just have "Today" and navigation buttons - without any data. Only after clicking on "Today" button that my calendar is rendered. Is there anything that i've forgotten?

The JSON File:

```
[{
    "title": "Title",
    "color": "#3c8dbc",
    "start": "2016-10-17"
}, {
    "title": "Title",
    "color": "#3c8dbc",
    "start": "2016-10-18"
}]
```

Comment: Can we see the code where you load the data coming from the JSON file?

Comment: I've edited with JSON file. But, after clicking "Today" button, everything is ok and FC is showed normally.

Answer (score 1):

After searching for a reason, i've found that due calendar is hidden, the "render" does not worked properly.

To fix it, i've added a function on modal open callback:

```
$("#myModal").on('show.bs.modal',function(){
    setTimeout(function(){$("#calendar").fullCalendar('render')}, 300);
});
```